# videoView XML file is showing error !

Tags: android

Error in the following XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:id="@+id/videoView" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The error shown is :
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not 
     allowed.
    - No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the 
     document.

[image: error snapshot]

Request someone to let me know how can i resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

try using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and try cleanining you project! hope helps!